# How do I calculate the difference of two angle measures?

Tags: java, math, geometry

How can I calculate the difference of two angle measures (given in degrees) in Java so the result is in the range [0°, 180°]?

For example:

```
350° to 15° = 25°
250° to 190° = 60°
```

Comment: If you're calculating distance, why is the result in degrees?

Comment: Can you clarify - are you looking for something built in or are you just asking for a method? also should it take direction into account? Your first example is 25 degrees clockwise and your second is 60 degrees anticlockwise. If you just want the shortest distance then your results should be 0 to 180 (or -180 to 180 if you want to show direction).

Comment: Btw you should not allow 360 because 360 = 0. The domain of the entry arguments should be [0, 360).

Comment: Edited for clarity; feel free to roll back if this isn't what you really wanted.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
    /**
     * Shortest distance (angular) between two angles.
     * It will be in range [0, 180].
     */
    public static int distance(int alpha, int beta) {
        int phi = Math.abs(beta - alpha) % 360;       // This is either the distance or 360 - distance
        int distance = phi > 180 ? 360 - phi : phi;
        return distance;
    }
```

Comment: and for "Signed difference", append the following code... 

int sign = (a - b >= 0 && a - b <= 180)
|| (a - b <= -180 && a- b>= -360) ? 1 : -1;
r *= sign;

Comment: This really helped me, thank you.

Answer (score 26):

In addition to Nickes answer, if u want "Signed difference"

```
int d = Math.abs(a - b) % 360; 
int r = d > 180 ? 360 - d : d;

//calculate sign 
int sign = (a - b >= 0 && a - b <= 180) || (a - b <=-180 && a- b>= -360) ? 1 : -1; 
r *= sign;
```

EDITED:

Where 'a' and 'b' are two angles to find the difference of.

'd' is difference. 'r' is result / final difference.

Comment: What do `d` and `r` represent in this context? Difference and rotation?

Comment: I assume `a` and `b` represent `targetAngle` and `currentAngle` respectively.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro  yes that's right

Comment: This does not work properly for negative angles. For instance, the sign between 0 and -380 is negative, but the sign between 0 and -20 is positive. Easy fix is to set a=(a+360)%360, b=(b+360)%360. This won't work for angles that are below -360 though.

Comment: Had a night to think about it. Make all angles (a and b) positive before calculating sign by doing the following: 

`if(a < 0) a = 360 - ((-a) % 360);`
`else a = a % 360;`

Comment: @StevenVascellaro thanks for pointing out. I have added the details to my answer.

Comment: @usman Why not use self-descriptive variable names instead?

Answer (score 9):

Just take the absolute value of their difference, then, if larger than 180, substract 360° and take the absolute value of the result.

Answer (score 5):

Just do

```
(15 - 350) % 360
```

If the direction doesn't matter (you want the one that yields the smallest value), then do the reverse subtraction (mod 360) and calculate the smallest value of the two (e.g. with `Math.min`).

Comment: can you explain a little more? i dont understand you "then do the reverse subtraction (mod 360) and calculate the smallest value."

Comment: @And I mean doing also (350 - 15) % 360.

Comment: min((a-b)%360, (b-a)%360)  @AndroidUser99

Comment: @Artefacto Can you append an example of "Reverse subtraction" to your answer for a non-direction specific answer?

Answer (score 4):

How about the following:

```
dist = (a - b + 360) % 360;
if (dist > 180) dist = 360 - dist;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diff = MAX(angle1, angle2) - MIN(angle1, angle2);  
if (diff > 180) diff = 360 - diff;
```