# Angle difference between -180 and 180

Tags: java, geometry

I know a way to find the angle difference of two angles between [0,180], but I'm trying to find out a way to find the angle difference of two angles between [-179,180].

My code is as follows; it doesn't work properly:

```
private int distance2(int alpha, int beta) {
    int phi = beta - alpha;// % 360;    // This is either the distance or 360 - distance
    int distance = 0;
    if (phi < -360) {
        distance = 360 + phi;
    } // end of if
    else{
        distance = phi;  
    }
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878907/the-smallest-difference-between-2-angles

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, it worked as it should :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The smallest difference between 2 Angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878907/the-smallest-difference-between-2-angles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that alpha and beta are both in [-180, 180] interval, you know

-360 <= alpha - beta <= 360

So you can use:

```
private int distance2(int alpha, int beta) {
    int distance = beta - alpha;      // This is the distance mod 360
    if (phi <= -180) {
        distance += 360; // you were between -360 and -180 -> 0 <= distance <= 180
    else if (phi > 180) {
        distance -= 360; // you were between 180 and 360 -> 180 < distance <= 0
    }
    return distance;
}
```

If you cannot be sure of input values, just replace first line with:

```
int distance = (beta - alpha) % 360;  // forces distance in ]-360, 360[ range
```

Comment: Rakesh already helped me, but this does excactly the same so if people visit this topic, this is the way to go

Comment: What is `phi` in this snippet?

Answer (score 0):

This is just do

```
package angle;

public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(distance(-179,180));
}

private static double distance(double alpha, double beta) {
    if(beta>=0 && alpha >=0 && beta<=180 && alpha<=180){
        double phi = (beta - alpha) % 360;       // This is either the distance or 360 - distance
        double distance = phi > 180 ? 360 - phi : phi;
        return distance;
    }else if(beta<0 || alpha < 0){
        double phi = (beta - alpha) % 360;       // This is either the distance or 360 - distance
        double distance = phi;
        return distance;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

prints 359.0 you can reduce it to 360-distance to get smallest distance

replacing with double distance = phi > 180 ? 360 - phi : phi;

Also Refer to

[How do I calculate the difference of two angle measures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570808/how-do-i-calculate-the-difference-of-two-angle-measures)

Answer (score 0):

```
float diff(float a1, float a2)
{
    float a = a2 - a1;
    return abs((a > PI) ? a - 2 * PI : a);
}
```

abs - is optional in this function

works good in any cases