# Elegant (most efficient) way to check whether the angle falls into the circular confidence interval

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, scipy

I have the following sample dataset:

```
In [222]: df
Out[222]:
    ci_low  circ_time_angle  ci_high
0       30               30       30
1       10                0       20
2     -188              143      207
3     -188                4      207
4     -188                8      207
5     -188               14      207
6     -188              327      207
7      242               57      474
8      242              283      474
9      242                4      474
10    -190              200       -1
11     -90              300        0
12     -25               15       60
13     -30              349      350
14     420               30      600
15    -100               23      719
16    -100               23      259
17    -350                5      -10
18    -350               11      -10
```

where:

- `ci_low` - is a lower bound of a circular confidence interval (CI)
- `circ_time_angle` - is an angle that I want to check whether it falls into CI or not
- `ci_high` - is an upper bound of a circular confidence interval (CI)

**Constraints:**

- `0 <= circ_time_angle <= 360`
- `ci_high >= ci_low`
- `ci_low` and `ci_high` do **NOT** necessarily belong to `[0, 360]` (see rows `[2-18]` in the sample dataset).

**Question:** what would be the *elegant* way to check whether the angle `circ_time_angle` falls into circular confidence interval: `[ci_low, ci_high]`?
Or do I need to check separately all the edge cases?

**Desired / resulting dataset:**

```
In [224]: res
Out[224]:
    ci_low  circ_time_angle  ci_high  falls_into_CI
0       30               30       30           True
1       10                0       20          False
2     -188              143      207           True
3     -188                4      207           True
4     -188                8      207           True
5     -188               14      207           True
6     -188              327      207           True
7      242               57      474           True
8      242              283      474           True
9      242                4      474           True
10    -190              200       -1           True
11     -90              300        0           True
12     -25               15       60           True
13     -30              349      350           True
14     420               30      600          False
15    -100               23      719           True
16    -100               23      259           True
17    -350                5      -10          False
18    -350               11      -10           True
```

I also tried to convert CI boundaries to `[0, 360]` and to `[-180, 180]`, but it still didn't help me to find an elegant formula.

---

**Sample dataset setup:**

```html
data = {
'ci_low': [30,
  10,
  -188,
  -188,
  -188,
  -188,
  -188,
  242,
  242,
  242,
  -190,
  -90,
  -25,
  -30,
  420,
  -100,
  -100,
  -350,
  -350],
 'circ_time_angle': [30,
  0,
  143,
  4,
  8,
  14,
  327,
  57,
  283,
  4,
  200,
  300,
  15,
  349,
  30,
  23,
  23,
  5,
  11],
 'ci_high': [30,
  20,
  207,
  207,
  207,
  207,
  207,
  474,
  474,
  474,
  -1,
  0,
  60,
  350,
  600,
  719,
  259,
  -10,
  -10]}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: You could try to not use eval :) `df['falls_in_CI'] = df['ci_low'] <= df['circ_time_angle'] <= df['ci_high']`

Comment: There is a lot of code out there so solve this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878907/the-smallest-difference-between-2-angles

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570808/how-do-i-calculate-the-difference-of-two-angle-measures

Comment: @Joe, thank you for the links! I'm checking them now...

Answer (score 1):

Currently I've come up with the following idea:

1. check those CI intervals covering 360+ degrees and set result to `True` for the corresponding rows
2. for all other rows, rotate **all** angles (columns: `['ci_low', 'circ_time_angle', 'ci_high']`) in the way that `ci_low == 0` and compare *rotated* `circ_time_angle % 360 <= ci_high % 360`

---

Code:

```
def angle_falls_into_interval(angle, lower, upper, high=360):
    # rotate ALL angles in the way, 
    # so that the lower angle = 0 degrees / radians.
    lower = np.asarray(lower)
    angle = np.asarray(angle) - lower
    upper = np.asarray(upper) - lower
    lower -= lower
    return np.where(upper-lower >= high, 
                    True, 
                    (angle % high) <= (upper % high))
```

Check:

```
In [232]: res = df.assign(falls_into_CI=angle_falls_into_interval(df.circ_time_angle, 
                                                                  df.ci_low, 
                                                                  df.ci_high,
                                                                  high=360))

In [233]: res
Out[233]:
    ci_low  circ_time_angle  ci_high  falls_into_CI
0       30               30       30           True
1       10                0       20          False
2     -188              143      207           True
3     -188                4      207           True
4     -188                8      207           True
5     -188               14      207           True
6     -188              327      207           True
7      242               57      474           True
8      242              283      474           True
9      242                4      474           True
10    -190              200       -1           True
11     -90              300        0           True
12     -25               15       60           True
13     -30              349      350           True
14     420               30      600          False
15    -100               23      719           True
16    -100               23      259           True
17    -350                5      -10          False
18    -350               11      -10           True
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to normalize ci_low in the [0:360) range, and change `ci_high` by the same value. Then I would add 360 to `circ_time_angle` if it is below `ci_low`.

After that, the condition to be inside the CI interval is just `circ_time_angle<ci_high`.

I used an auxilliary dataframe to prevent any change in `df`:

```
limits = df[['ci_low', 'ci_high']].copy()   # copy ci_low and ci_high
limits.columns=['low', 'high']              # rename to have shorter names
# ensure ci_low is in the [0-360) range
delta = (limits['low'] // 360) * 360
limits['low'] -= delta
limits['high'] -= delta
limits['circ'] = df['circ_time_angle']      # copy circ_time_angle
# add 360 to circ_time_angle if it is below low
limits.loc[limits.circ < limits.low, 'circ'] += 360
df['falls_into_CI'] = limits['circ']<=limits['high']
```

It gives as expected:

```
    ci_low  circ_time_angle  ci_high  falls_into_CI
0       30               30       30           True
1       10                0       20          False
2     -188              143      207           True
3     -188                4      207           True
4     -188                8      207           True
5     -188               14      207           True
6     -188              327      207           True
7      242               57      474           True
8      242              283      474           True
9      242                4      474           True
10    -190              200       -1           True
11     -90              300        0           True
12     -25               15       60           True
13     -30              349      350           True
14     420               30      600          False
15    -100               23      719           True
16    -100               23      259           True
17    -350                5      -10          False
18    -350               11      -10           True
```

The nice point here if that everything is vectorized.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think this is not quite correct... My goal is to check whether an angle falls into the specified confidence interval. If the confidence interval is `[-188, 207]`, then this CI covers the whole circle (`207 - -188 == 395`) and thus the result must be `True`. The same applies to `[-100, 719]`.

Comment: @MaxU: Ok, I will have to slightly change my approach then.

Comment: yep, it looks good now. :) Your idea is similar to one I have used in my answer ;)