# Find relative angle between two points

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, angle

I am designing a web script to automatically create a Java file to perform autonomous actions for a robotics team based on nodes created by the player. It also features a simulation to check collision (I could use an algorithm to do this but sometimes we want it to hit the walls). The robot takes relative degrees, but `atan2` gives radians on the unit circle. If I use `atan`, it just doesn't work right. I've tried this:

```
function findDegrees(node1, node2){
  return Math.atan((node2.y - node1.y) / (node2.x - node1.x)) * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

But it just doesn't work. This piece of code writes the data too the output. (Also, I'm following the pattern: Drive, then turn towards next node).

```
  let theta = currentAngle - findDegrees(nextNode, twoNodes);
  currentAngle += theta;
  if (theta && typeof theta !== 'undefined'){
    middle += `${INDENTSPACE}turn(${theta}, 1.0);\n`;
  }
```

The way I change the x and y of the robot simulation is this:

```
turn(degrees, speed){
  this.theta -= degrees;
}
```

But sometimes it goes the other way. **How do I get the robot to rotate at a relative angle to the current angle where directly forward is 0°?** (If you want the full code [here it is](https://github.com/ArkinSolomon/SPQR-Web-App).)

Comment: This post might have some useful ideas for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570808/how-do-i-calculate-the-difference-of-two-angle-measures